# Show debug toolbar on Android Monitor Android Studio 1.4 preview 3

Tags: android-studio

Ok... I'm sure that I was able to do this on previous versions. I just want to be able to step while watching logcat at the same time. They are now on separate panes. Is there a way to show the debug toolbars with step options on the Android Monitor/logcat tab? Right now I can do it by detaching and resizing panes but it is painful. Or can I just "lock" the debug toolbar on the side of the screen somewhere? BTW. I know about using split but I really would like the debugger tab and the logcat tab full size.

Comment: +1 I've noticed the same behaviour with AS 1.4. Logcat is now in the Android Monitor tab and I'd like to know if there is an option to have it in the Debug tab.

Comment: +1 I've upgraded to AS 1.4 today and I too noticed that there's no longer a "logcat" tab in the "debugger" pane.
It seems the only option is to put the two navigators "Debugger" and "Android Monitor" side by side.
I can see why they did it though - it was probably redundant having the logcat in two places.